# kendo datepicker remove default css class k-picker-wrap

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am using the Kendo-datepicker,i want to remove the CSS class "`k-picker-wrap`" which is appending to span tag inbuilt is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to remove it. There is no such configuration provided. However you can use your own class to override the default css.

```
$("#someid .k-picker-wrap").css({ /*any css property*/ });
```

In css:

```
#someSelector .k-picker-wrap{

  /*any css property*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks,but how  i can override it,its inside the span tag.

Comment: you will have to use jquery selector to select it and then update its css.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove directly, but you can do something like this in your js:

```
$(".k-picker-wrap").css({ 'background-color' : '', 'color' : '' });
```

To all ".k-picker-wrap" css proprietes.

or you can alter in your custom css like: (just an example i dont even run it)

```
#yorContainer > span >.k-picker-wrap{

"background-color" : "", 
"color" : "" 

}
```

hope this help